# How to run a Deployment Group Job in one of the matching servers?

Tags: azure-devops

I have multiple local on-prem agents that can run a particular deployment group job (for the purpose of load balancing). I want only the first available one to run the job and not all of them. Which setting of the Deployment Group Job I can use to do that? My only options seems to be "Multiple" and "Single at a time" both of which run the jobs on all servers matching the Required Tags.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the updated answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I want only the first available one to run the job and not all of them. Which setting of the Deployment Group Job I can use to do that?

There is an option for the Release pipeline with Deployment Group job **Required tags**：

[image]

Then we just need to add the tag to the machine, which we want to deploy:

[image]

Now, the release pipeline will run a Deployment Group Job in one of the matching servers.

**Update:**

> I do have the required tag, but on two agent servers. I want the Job
> to pick only one of the two matching servers and run the job on it
> instead of running it on both.

As workaround, you could create a private agent pool and add two or more agents in it. Those agents are deployed on different machines. With this way, the pipeline will executed on one of the agent.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I do have the required tag, but on two agent servers. I want the Job to pick only one of the two matching servers and run the job on it instead of running it on both.

Comment: @fahadash, So your purpose is not to restrict it to be executed on one of the two machines, but to randomly select one of the two machines to run instead of running both, right? If yes, I am afraid there is no such way to achieve this at this moment.

Comment: @fahadash, After replying to you, I suddenly realized that all you need is private agent. Deployment group is a logical set of deployment target machines that have agents installed on each one. If you just execute on the pipeline on one of agents, you could use private agent. To be executed on each machine is the original intention of the Deployment group.